# authselect vs ssh key in a tiny network

Tags: centos, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to setup a tiny LAN (2 - 3 Linux computers) with a wifi router and CentOS 8.

Does authselect provide any security benefit over ssh keys?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[authselect](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/using_authselect_on_a_red_hat_enterprise_linux_host/index) and SSH keys serve different purposes. authselect configures name lookup (NSS) and authentication (PAM) policy. SSH key pairs are secrets for SSH `publickey` authentication.

How exactly to use all of these components requires more details on how you want users to be identified and authenticated.